# Was the character of Dumbledore in Harry Potter Gay?

Tags: harry-potter

I was just wondering if Dumbledore is gay? The portrayal of his character in the movie gave me that impression. Is there any canon information about his sexual orientation?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Scifi.SE! You are being downvoted because of the "any opinions will do" part of your question. This site does not support discussion. Please read the [help section](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) to understand better what you can/cannot ask here. Also, a little research would have probably get you the answer.

Comment: @Kalissar question has been edited

Comment: This question already has an answer here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41282/did-j-k-rowing-always-consider-dumbledore-gay?lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Yes, JKR has always thought of him as gay.](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more)

However, sexuality not being the main topic of HP, this was not explicitly stated within the story.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that JKR said Dumbledore was in love with Grindelwald (not necessarily returned) which was why Dumbledore was both swayed by Grindelwald's anti-Muggle arguments and delayed in fighting him.  http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more

Comment: It's sad to me that you don't see this as a main topic of the story, given the importance of the theme of love throughout the series--particularly evinced by Dumbledore himself.

Comment: @thumbtackthief I totally agree with you. Love is a very important part of the story. Sexuality is not. Is the difference not clear enough that I have to make it explicit in the answer ?

Comment: @Kalissar No thank you; I've had more than enough straight people try to tell me that love and sexuality are divorced when it comes to gay people.  If you can't see the difference between Dumbledore's love for Grindelwald than for Harry, for example, then I can't help you.